# Creating a Heroku add-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, add-on

I would like to integrate my cloud service in Heroku as an add-on. I read the available tutorials on how to do this, but it is still not clear. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-heroku-add-on#provisioning

I couldn't understand the role of the application that we create from a template (Sinatra for example) using **kensa**.
Is it an intermediate between Heroku and the cloud service?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Heroku needs 2 things:

1. addon-manifest.json file where described all information needed for Heroku. And this json file contains 2 important urls:

   - 'base_url'
   - 'sso_url'
2. Application which will server heroku-specific API and responds wit corresponding JSON on provisioning/deprovisioning/planchange requests. These request point to 'base_url'.

So, if you own your Cloud service code, and can add new API endpoints, then you don't need any application based on kensa-template: add necessary API controllers directly in the service.

But if you can't upgrade the cloud service, then you're right, kensa-template is a ready to use with heroku intermediate.

In case of sinatra template, you just need to put necessary API calls to your cloud service in "# provision" method of app.rb file, deploy app somewhere and do 'kensa push' for your addon-manifest.json (don;t forget to update base_url to yours)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But what are exactly the API endpoints that I need to implement in my "Cloud service" code? Only the provisioning/deprovisioning/planchange requests?

Answer (score 1):

Bare minimum API routes for heroku add-on based on your Cloud service:

- POST request to '/heroku/resources' - for provisioning
- DELETE request to '/heroku/resources' - for deprovisioning

If you really want to sell it to heroku users, then you should do more stuff:

- add support for [heroku single sign-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-on-single-sign-on)
  this is one more API route:  POST to '/heroku/sso', but you can change it in addon-manifest.json file.
- PUT '/heroku/resources/:id' for Plan change request. Note that ':id' is an id which you provided heroku in your response during provisioning.

If you implement SSO, then user can click on your add-on on heroku instance's resources page and redirect directly to your service bypass any login forms.
You can show just short info about user's resource in the page after SSO.

Comment: Does the provisioning process change when we use Single Sign-on(SSO)? thanks